# Cassandra: Active: failed (Result: exit-code)

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-4.0

I installed the cassandra 3.11.11 in the Centos 7. I configurated the cassandra.service. When I ran, the error below appear:

**EDIT**

```
● cassandra.service - Apache
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/cassandra.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-09-30 12:22:08 EDT; 2min 6s ago
  Process: 5972 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cassandra -f -p /var/run/cassandra/cassandra.pidx (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 5972 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Sep 30 12:22:08 GDBDEV08 systemd[1]: Started Apache.
Sep 30 12:22:08 GDBDEV08 systemd[1]: cassandra.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Sep 30 12:22:08 GDBDEV08 systemd[1]: Unit cassandra.service entered failed state.
Sep 30 12:22:08 GDBDEV08 systemd[1]: cassandra.service failed.
```

/etc/systemd/system/Cassandra.server

```
[Unit]
Description=Apache
Cassandra After=network.target
[Service]
PIDFile=/var/run/cassandra/cassandra.pid
User=cassandra
Group=cassandra
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/cassandra -f -p /var/run/cassandra/cassandra.pidx
```

Comment: Hmm.  Maybe `tail` the log and see what the last entries are?

Comment: It was fixed a conflit in the user and group, but the service didn't start. I'm cheking the log! Thanks

Comment: I found  this error  `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon` . Could you help me?

Comment: It's hard to say exactly what's happening.  Which version of Cassandra are you using?  Anything special about it (custom Docker image, fork of K8ssandra, etc)?  Basically, have a look at `bin/cassandra.in.sh`.  Somehow Cassandra's `lib/` dir isn't making it into `$CASSANDRA_HOME`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all! I'll review all. It's the first time using docker image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With very little information, it's hard to guess at why it's failing.

For what it's worth, Cassandra 3.11 only works with Java 8. If you're using a newer Java release, that would explain why you're getting the "class not found" error.

As Aaron suggested, you need to check the logs for startup errors. You will need to update your original question and post the full error message + full stacktrace so we could tell you why it failed to start. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I think there is something wrong with my `cassandra.service`. The  "class not found" error occured when I tried manually. I downloaded the binary version, not the source. I'll try install again! I'm testing install in several OS.